# Cron not running a command properly

Tags: server, cron

I have HP ProLiant Utilities installed on my Ubuntu Server. Using the following shell command I am able to save the output of the RAID status to a log file:

```
sudo ssacli ctrl all show config > /var/logs/raid.log
```

I then tried to create a cron job so that on a daily basis the log file is overwritten with the status. My cron job looks like this:

```
30 15 * * * ssacli ctrl all show config > /var/logs/raid.log #Log RAID Status
```

This cron job is for root user.

The problem is that, if I go to Webmin and run this cron job by pressing "Save & Run Now" the log file is created. But if I let the cron job run at it's designated time, the log file is created but is blank.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that I need to run the ssacli in sudo mode

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: First rule of `cron`: always provide full paths. In this case, you may need to write `/usr/bin/ssacli` instead of `ssacli`. The executable `ssacli` may be found somewhere else than in `/usr/bin/`; you can find out where with `which ssacli`.

Comment: Awesome. thanks. that was it. I just had to put full path to ssacli which was /usr/sbin/ssacli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.